# google maps with my application

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps

hello i want to use google maps with my java web app..
is there any possiblity to use it , edit (mark regions, naming those regions) and save it ?

Answer (score 3):

yes, it has a javascript API.  Check out the documentation; it's pretty good: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/